# How to enable ReadConcernMajority in MongoDB 3.6.3?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I'm running a MongoDB 3.6.3 with pymongo. I would like to use `watch` on a collection but it returns the following error: `ReadConcernMajorityNotEnabled`. Can anyone tell me how to enable it please?

thanks

Comment: Read concern majority should be enabled by default in MongoDB 3.6 but requires that you are using the WiredTiger storage engine and a replica set with protocol version 1 (`pv1`). Does your deployment meet both of these requirements? Is this a new deployment or have you upgraded from a prior major release of MongoDB? You can check the protocol version with `rs.conf().protocolVersion`.

Comment: Hi, i check and I'm using ```pv1``` and yes I'm using a replica started with the command ```mongod --replSet rs0 --enableMajorityReadConcern --dbpath ./db0/```. Do you think I'm missing something else?

Comment: Was this a new deployment created with MongoDB 3.6.3 or did you upgrade from an earlier release series of MongoDB (eg. 3.4)? What specific version of PyMongo and O/S are you using?

Comment: @Stennie it was enough to remove or create another one for the db... Your comments made me think. I'm happy to let you amend your answer and I'll select it as the right one! Super thanks

Comment: I'm still curious as to why read concern majority wasn't enabled by default for your deployment. My guess is that you upgraded from a prior version of MongoDB and missed the step to [enable backwards-incompatible 3.6 features](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.6-upgrade-replica-set/#enable-backwards-incompatible-newversion-features) using `db.adminCommand( { setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: "3.6" } )`. Can you confirm if that was the case?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay... Yes that was the case. Thanks again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Read concern majority](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/read-concern/#readconcern._dq_majority_dq_) should be enabled by default in MongoDB 3.6 but there are several requirements to note if you have upgraded from a prior major MongoDB release or changed default configuration values.

Server configuration settings to check:

- **Your deployment is using the WiredTiger storage engine**

  > `db.serverStatus().storageEngine` should include `"name": "wiredTiger"`

  *If you need to change this, see: [Change Replica Set to WiredTiger](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/change-replica-set-wiredtiger/#change-replica-set-to-wiredtiger).*
- **Replication is enabled with protocol version 1 (`pv1`)**

  > `rs.conf().protocolVersion` should be `NumberLong("1")`

  *If you need to change this, see: [Modify Replica Set Protocol Version](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/replica-set-protocol-versions/#modify-replica-set-protocol-version).*
- **3.6 feature compatibility is enabled**

  > `db.adminCommand({getParameter: 1, featureCompatibilityVersion: 1})` should include  `"version": "3.6"`

  *If you need to change this, see: [Enable backwards-incompatible 3.6 features](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.6-upgrade-replica-set/#enable-backwards-incompatible-newversion-features).*

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!