# MongoError: Majority read concern requested, but it is not supported by the storage engine

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mlab

I am using mlab free tier, and I'm trying to use change streams in my app. Here's my code:

```
const config = require('../globals/config');
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
MongoClient.connect(config.db, {useNewUrlParser: true}, function (err, client) {
    const db = client.db('web-project-studio-db');
    // Connect using MongoClient
    var filter = [{$match: {'_id': user._id}}];

    db.collection('accounts').watch(filter).on('change', data => {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

This says:

> MongoError: Majority read concern requested, but it is not supported by the storage engine.

Is there something I should enable in mlab settings, or did I just mess something up?

Comment: which version of mongo you are running in mlab?

Comment: How can I check this?

Comment: This should help to find it on the console: https://docs.mlab.com/ops/, but It should 3.6 looking docs.
Reading this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49572024/how-to-enable-readconcernmajority-in-mongodb-3-6-3 it seems that mlab doesn't configure the `readConcern`. You may ask to support@mlab.com to confirm

Comment: I already moved past this issue since it was asked over 4 months ago, but if I hit it again I'll take a deeper look into it. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Sorry I don't understand: did you solve it or did you change something else?

Comment: I just used a timeout to get the data via API endpoint. Not the best option, but it works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use `watch` you need to use replica set which is not part of mLab [free plan](https://mlab.com/plans/pricing/).